# Is there any logic to who is the Game Champion?

Tags: apex-legends

I always thought that the game 'Champion' announced before the drop was the player with the highest KD, or the highest level player that was put in the game with you.

But yesterday I got a guy that was the champion who was level 4 with 2 kills. So I'm now wondering: Is there any logic for the game champion? Or does it take a random player and makes him the marked man for the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my personal in game experience it seems to be whoever had the best standing the round before. **Placement** seems to be the thing that decides it but sometimes there will be multiple people who won from the last round where it then checks for **Points (Respawns, Kills, Revives, ect.)**

[This link](https://answers.ea.com/t5/General-Discussion/How-is-Champion-determined/td-p/7848327) has an answer from someone backing up what I said but also saying that **Distance Traveled** and **Weapon Accuracy** might come into play.

There isn't any official source saying what determines the champion squad so the only way to get an answer would be to experiment in game but that would still be hard with there being 60 players per game with no way to tell how the champion did last round.

Comment: I may refer to my comment on the other answer, that this doesn't quite match my experience: `Then again, yesterday I was champ, failed horribly next game (died after 2-3 min) and was again champ in the game after`

Comment: Well that could mean that everyone else in your game failed even worse. While that is very unlikely it still has a chance of happening.

Comment: There are several other people who experienced something alike. Some people even tried to test it with friends and couldn't get a definitive answer. The right answer to the question would be that its unknown as there is no credible source saying otherwise and there are too many experiences opposing what you experienced

Answer (score 5):

It is not random.

I have been champion only once and it was following being the "Champion" from the previous round, which meant getting the most kills, dealing the final blow, and being in the final squad.

I believe the marked champion is the player in the round who went the farthest in the previous round, generally from 60 players there is one who was the actual "Champion" (it announces that for you if you win). I am not sure what metric is used for tie breaking.

Keep in mind, the players in the current group with you compose the current round. None of them may have been in the squad which won in the previous round. It is possible as a result that the champion chosen was not actually the winner of a previous round, although unlikely, especially since the game has been around for quite some time now.

As for the kills, or the level, that is just on the banner, **and** is specific to that legend. So, if I have 1000 kills with Lifeline, but switch to using Bloodhound who I have only had 10 kills with, it will only show the kills I earned with Bloodhound (10). The level is always the same, but the display may change from banner to banner.

Comment: This can't be 100% right, unless its been changed with the most recent update. As already commented `Then again, yesterday I was champ, failed horribly next game (died after 2-3 min) and was again champ in the game after`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer - At the time I was level 6 having only 14 total kills (6 of them coming from that match). Perhaps it is the past two matches? Also, it is possible that that user's squad performed better once they left? Unsure. I agree that it is not 100% right though, this is only a surmisal of what I *believe* the marked champion is.

Comment: Also yesterday I got a champion that was a level 1 account. So my best guess would be a weighted random.

Comment: @Fredy31 - I *highly* doubt that it is weighted random. It literally says "Top ranked last match" above the Champion. Their first match team must have been the last one standing while the lower level player did not achieve victory themselves enough to level.

Comment: I don't remember how much XP I needed to level up, but my first game was something very basic like 2 kills ranked something like 11 and I leveled. Put into that that it seems that XP is heavily weighted towards survival time and he should have leveled up. I should have taken a screenshot but I didnt.